# Modify snapshot data within firestore function?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've got a onWrite() function that gets called whenever a document is added. These documents are being created by the client, and I need to add some extra fields to it.

Is there a way to modify the document snapshot that triggered the function call, before it hits the database?

Or do I need to make a separate update call into the database to add the fields? (And, if so, will this extra call trigger another onWrite() call to my function?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to modify the document snapshot that triggered the function > call, before it hits the database?

You can't intercept a write to the database before it gets to a trigger.  The trigger is always going to happen *after* the write from the client.

> Or do I need to make a separate update call into the database to add the fields?

Yes, you can modify the database inside the trigger.  This is a very common use case.

> And, if so, will this extra call trigger another onWrite() call to my function?

If you modify the same document that triggered an onWrite function, yes, it will trigger the function again.  You will have to defend against this case by checking, in your function code, if another write should happen.  Also consider using onCreate instead, if you don't want a modified document to trigger the function again.